# Using Galera Cluster(Percona XtraDB Cluster, MariaDB Cluster) for setting up multi master

Tags: mysql, replication, clustering, galera, xtradb-cluster

Before i gotta use one I want to know if it is working in windows OS cause I saw a lot using it in linux OS. Does using galera (Percona XtraDB Cluster, MariaDB Cluster) cluster works in windows?

Answer (score 0):

it does not so far. I suggested it to Codership (the creator of Galera) to port it to Windows but somehow I did not have luck with my suggestion.

But we (fromdual.com) would be happy to help you setting it up and operating it on Linux?

Regards,
Oli